# Using completely custom views with admob in android

Tags: android, layout, view, admob

I am having real problems understanding Layouts. I am trying to put admob into my app, but up until this point i have had no reason to use a layout. I'll show you what I have in my activity class.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View tfview = new TFView(this);
    setContentView(tfview);}
```

I then proceed to have the entirety of my application written in Java, without the use of any XML. How to I put both this view and the Admob onto a layout? I tried adding both of them to the layout by doing this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, pubID);
    layout.addView(adView);
    layout.addView(tfview);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

but I receive some sort of null pointer exception errors. Can Anybody help?

Thanks in advance
-Derek

Comment: Can you post the null pointer exception errors?

Comment: By the way, welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response helpful, please upvote it. If you find that a response answers your question, please accept it.

Comment: null pointer is here, http://shrib.com/VRCyCu5Y

EDIT: Line 51 is layout.addView(adView);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all of your responses. I eventually just read some other responses to similar questions and built my layout on programatically(if thats a word). So basically I did this:

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, pubID);

    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams gameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams adsParams =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM|android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); 
    layout.addView(tfview, gameParams);
    layout.addView(adView, adsParams);
    setContentView(layout);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

And it works like a charm. Thanks again to all of you.

-Derek

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a game where i never need to use any xml layout. I had some custom views and I was not able to put the banner ads. But your answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that R.id.linearLayout is actually a valid Id that corresponds to the view to which you want to add your admob content.

If you want to get a better handle on XML Layouts (which I suggest you do, becuase they really are the way you should be doing layouts in android), checkout the [HelloViews tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html).

Comment: I made a new xml file and added the following code to it.
    <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    
</LinearLayout>

Then I renamed to R.id.layout
Am I doing something wrong here? Like I said, I just dont understand layouts very well.

Comment: That's correct, is the code still not working? Also, see my edited reasponse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your xml file is `main.xml` in the `res/layout` folder, then set the content view to your `main.xml` file.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Setting the contentView defines where you are pulling your resources from.  Your xml file looks fine from your comment on Kurtis's answer, but you have to set the xml file as the contentView in order to be able to reference its layouts.  That is why you can't find that view, so your `layout` variable is null, and it eventually causes the exception.

Comment: yea i did that, and it still didnt like it.